# Powershell Out-File Doesn't Work For CSV

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$databaseContents = "col1,col2,col3,col4"
$theDatabaseFile = "C:\NewFolder\Database.csv
$databaseContents | Out-File $theDatabaseFile
```

However when I open the csv file in Excel, it has col1,col2,col3,col4 in cell A1 rather than col1 in cell A1, col2 in cell B1 etc.

Something strange I've noticed:
If I open the file in Notepad and copy the text into another Notepad instance and save it as Database1.csv, then open it in Excel, it displays as expected.

How can I get the `Out-File` commandlet to save it as a .csv file with the contents in 4 columns as expected?

**EDIT:
I've noticed if I use `Set-Content` rather than `Out-File`, the csv file is then displayed correctly in Excel. 
Does anyone know why this is?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why it makes a difference to Excel I am unclear, but it comes down to the encoding of the resulting output file - Unicode (in the cases that do not work) vs. ASCII (in the cases that do).

[image: PowerShell Out-File vs. Set-Content to a CSV File]

@JPBlanc's alternate approach works because it sets the encoding of the output file to ASCII where your original example (implicitly) set the encoding of the output file to Unicode.

Just adding `-Encoding ascii` to your original example works fine too:

```
$databaseContents = "col1,col2,col3,col4"
$theDatabaseFile = "C:\NewFolder\Database.csv
$databaseContents | Out-File $theDatabaseFile -Encoding ascii
```

And adding an explicit `-Encoding unicode` to your original example yields the same broken result you encountered:

```
$databaseContents = "col1,col2,col3,col4"
$theDatabaseFile = "C:\NewFolder\Database.csv
$databaseContents | Out-File $theDatabaseFile -Encoding unicode
```

This is basically what was happening implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
So basically if excel reads text that is encoded in any encoding other than ascii, it will just treat it as pure text? Ie. it won't read the commas as separating values.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave: That's a reasonable hypothesis, but I admittedly don't grok Excel subtly enough to say for sure.  The original `Out-File`-produced `Database.csv` worked fine (i.e. showing `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, and `col4` in cells `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, and `A4` respectively) _if_ rather than double-clicking it to open it in Excel I first opened Excel, then opened it through Excel and went through the Text Import Wizard.  Maybe someone with relevant Excel expertise can say for sure why it cared about Unicode vs. ASCII in such a simple scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This works also :

```
$databaseContents = "col1;col2;col3;col4"
$theDatabaseFile = "C:\temp\Database.csv"
$databaseContents | Out-File $theDatabaseFile -Encoding ascii
```

By default CSV separator in Excel seams to be ';' and `Out-File` save as unicode forcing `ASCII` seams to give the result you look for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default separator is a comma, hence why it's called "comma separated values".
I tried using a semi colon but it didn't work.

What I did try was using -Encoding ascii while keeping the commas rather than replacing them with semi colons and it worked fine.

Comment: You are absolutly right CSV means coma separated values. But when I save an Excel file as CSV, by default Excel use ; that why I wrote that.

Comment: strange, for me it uses a comma when I save it as .csv

Comment: This is not the case for me. Perhaps it's because I use a french version

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem than **Backwards_Dave** and just like him, using the `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File` command worked for me:

```
#Build $temp String
$temp = "$scriptApplication;$applicationName;$type;$description;$maxSessions;$enabled;$tempParams`n"

#Write $temp String to $fichierCsv file
"$temp" | Set-Content $fichierCsv
```

I tried using **JPBlanc**'s and **J0e3gan**'s solution but it did not work (`-Encoding ascii` option): I wonder why.